# How to remove unwanted space between div content and border?

Tags: html, css

There is a small gap between `div` content and it's border *(on chromium-based browsers)*. Is there a way to remove it?

---

[codepen](https://codepen.io/unige/pen/gOrydbG)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjyk9.png)

---

```css
.group {
    border: solid 3px #580210;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-flex;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}

.label {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #580210;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Kavivanar', cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    user-select: none;
}

.input[type=radio]:checked+.label {
    color: #f5b339;
    background: #580210;
}

.label+.input[type=radio]+.label {
    border-left: solid 3px #580210;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
    <input type="radio" id="option-normal" name="selector" class="input">
    <label for="option-normal" class="label">Normal</label>
    <input type="radio" id="option-normal2" name="selector" class="input">
    <label for="option-normal2" class="label">Normal2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="option-normal3" name="selector" class="input">
    <label for="option-normal3" class="label">Normal3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Not reproducible in Chrome 85.0.4183.121 at 100% zoom - this seems to only occur at zoom-levels 80% and 90%.

Comment: nor firefoxe latest, what browser do you use ?

Comment: I use Google Chrome Version 85.0.4183.121 (without any extensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change the background-color of the `<div calss="group">` to be `#580210` instead of white and than overwrite the label styles to be white to make it look the same ?

Comment: This doesn't solve a problem, but it is a nice idea. Thanks! 
I'll wait for some time and mark it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, Thx and have a nice day